# calculate the predicted value based on coefficient and constant in python

Tags: python, pandas, regression, prediction, coefficients

i have the coefficients and the constant (alpha). i want to multiply and add the values together like this example. (it has to be done for 300000 rows)

> Prediction = constant + (valOfRow1 * col1) + (-valOfRow1  *
> col2) + (-valOfRow1 * col3) + (valOfRow1 *
> col4) + (valOfRow1 * col5)
>
> Prediction = 222 + (555-07 * col1) + (-555-07 * col2) + (-66* col3) +
> (55* col4) + (777* col5)

i have a one row dataframe which contains the coefficient and constant like this

|  | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | constant |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 2.447697e-07 | -5.214072e-07 | -0.000003 | 0.000006 | 555 | 222 |

and another dataframe with the exact same name but with monthly values.

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16711 | 17961 | 0 | 20 | 55 |

i already tried to sort the columns and then i take the product of them `df.dot`.

```
selected_columns = selected_columns.sort_index(axis=1)
#mean_coefficients dataframe 21th (starting from 0) is constant so i use the other columns
selected_columns['predicted_Mcap']=selected_columns.dot(mean_coefficients.iloc[:,0:20])+mean_coefficients['const']
```

the reason that i use `mean_coefficients.iloc[:,0:20]` is because i don't want to conclude `const` in the multiplication it just needs to be added at the end.

so i calculated the predicted value but when i checked it in excel the value wasn't the same.

am i calculating it right?

Comment: the operation works but wrong values or you get an error?

Comment: @ben.t when i try only for 10 rows `selected_columns.iloc[0:10,:].dot(mean_coefficients.iloc[:,0:20])+mean_coefficients['const'] ` i get `ValueError: matrices are not aligned`

Comment: ok, then try like this `selected_columns.dot(mean_coefficients.iloc[0,0:5])+mean_coefficients.loc[0,'constant'] `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentions in `df.dot()` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html#:%7E:text=The%20dimensions%20of%20DataFrame%20and%20other%20must%20be%20compatible%20in%20order%20to%20compute%20the%20matrix%20multiplication.%20In%20addition%2C%20the%20column%20names%20of%20DataFrame%20and%20the%20index%20of%20other%20must%20contain%20the%20same%20values%2C%20as%20they%20will%20be%20aligned%20prior%20to%20the%20multiplication.) the column names of DataFrame and the index of other must contain the same values, as they will be aligned prior to the multiplication. Otherwise you'll get

> ValueError: matrices are not aligned

so you have 2 Options:

to use the `df.dot()` with the `.T` or transposed dataframe. Your column names will be as indexes and is ready to be multiplied in a matrix way. Remember that the Column names in both dataframes has to be the same. Even one extra column returns error.

```
selected_columns['predicted_MCAP']=selected_columns.dot(mean_coefficients.iloc[:,1:21].T) + mean_coefficients['const']
```

in order to workaround this i by using numpy array

```
result = df1.dot(df2.values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if this method can solve your task:

```
import pandas as pd

# Load the coefficients and variables data frames
df_coefficients = pd.read_clipboard()
df_variables = pd.read_clipboard()


def predict(df_coefficients: pd.DataFrame, df_variables: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.Series:
    """
    Predicts the value of the dependent variable based on the values of the independent variables.
    :param df_coefficients: DataFrame with the coefficients of the independent variables.
    :param df_variables: DataFrame with the values of the independent variables.
    :return: Series with the predicted values of the dependent variable.
    """
    result = []
    # Convert the constants to a pandas Series and remove them from the coefficients DataFrame
    constants = df_coefficients.iloc[:]['constant']
    df_coefficients.drop(['constant'], inplace=True, axis=1)

    # Iterate over the rows of the coefficients DataFrame and calculate the prediction
    for idx, val in constants.items():
        prediction: float = val + (df_coefficients.iloc[idx][:] * df_variables.iloc[idx][:]).sum()
        print(f'prediction {idx}: {prediction}')
        result.append(prediction)
    return pd.DataFrame({'prediction': result})


result = predict(
    df_coefficients=df_coefficients, 
    df_variables=df_variables
)
result
```

prediction: 30746.99484535174

Best!

Comment: that's wrong value, the value shouldn't be more than 14 or 15. the values are in ln(The column) basis, in oreder to get the value you have to apply this formula: `y = e^ln(selected_columns['predicted_MCAP'])`  if i take your value and use it, it would return redicolous number and that was the hard part of the code.